# Possible NullreferenceException

Tags: c#, resharper, nullreferenceexception

Resharper is showing a "Possible System.NullReferenceException" warning. I however can't see how I can get one.

```
public class PlaceController : PlanningControllerBase
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult StartStop(int id)
    {
        if (Request != null && Request.Cookies != null && Request.Cookies["place"] != null)
        {
            if (Request.Cookies["place"].Value != null)//Possible NullReferenceException?
            {
                string placeInformation = Request.Cookies["place"].Value;//Possible NullReferenceException?
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can this give a NullReference if I check all fields? Using the following doesn't show the warning:

```
Request.Cookies[0];//Index instead of name
```

Edit: updated code.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to set the variable `placeInformation` when `Request.Cookies["place"].Value` is null or was that a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume the checker isn't checking the value of the string passed to the CookieCollection indexer is the same each time. I imagine if you restructure the code to:

```
if (Request != null && Request.Cookies != null) 
{
    var place = Request.Cookies["place"];
    if (place != null && place.Value == null) 
    { 
        string placeInformation = place.Value;
    } 
}
```

It might work.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to listen to every single warning. The `Request` object and the `Cookies` object will never be null so this is all you need.

```
var placeCookie = Request.Cookies["place"]; 
if (placeCookie != null)
{
    string placeInformation = placeCookie.Value;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, just writing "HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["place"];" works and shows no warnings.

Comment: @Carra - Just a side note, I think using indeed in your day to day vocabulary is indeed awesome.

Comment: English isn't my native language. I meant to use "Yes,...".

Comment: @Cara - I was not implying that you English was incorrect. I was simply saying that I like the word indeed from some strange reason.

Answer (score 0):

err don't you want `Request.Cookies["place"].Value != null`
, right now you will only be setting placeInformation  to null.